# How to load and start windows driver?

Tags: windows, load, drivers, ioctl

Hi I have a simple driver helloworld.sys inside that it has some print statements like kdprint("loaded successfully") etc.. now i need to load the driver and start the service. how to do that..??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Basically the driver should be registered as a service. Use `OpenSCManager` to access the service manager functions, then use `CreateService` to register your driver for the first time.

During the registration you select the driver start type. `SERVICE_BOOT_START` means the driver should be loaded during the boot time (very early stage of OS loading), `SERVICE_SYSTEM_START` means the driver should be loaded during the system load (this is typical more-or-less). You may also use `SERVICE_DEMAND_START` - the driver won't be loaded automatically.

Unless your driver is loaded automatically you should use `OpenService` to get access to its service, and `StartService` to actually start it.

The rest depends on what your driver actually does. If it creates a virtual device - you may access it by using `CreateFile`. Then use `DeviceIoControl` to actually communicate with it.

Answer (score 1):

See the below link where you can find everything you need to know from writing a driver to compiling and starting it:

[Introduction to Device Drivers](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/introduction-device-drivers)